# Counting Bits giving not the expected output

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, data-structures, ecmascript-6

Trying to solve the `Counting Bits using JavaScript` ,basically  `finding the number of set bits for all numbers from 0 to N and push them in an array and return as answer`

Here is explanation

```
            Input: n = 5
            Output: [0,1,1,2,1,2]
            Explanation:
            0 --> 0
            1 --> 1
            2 --> 10
            3 --> 11
            4 --> 100
            5 --> 101
```

Here is the solution in Javascript

```
                const countBits = function (nums){

                   let mem = [];
                   mem[0] = 0;
                   
                   
                   for (let i=0;i<=nums;i++)
                   
                     mem[i] = mem[i/2] + i%2;
                     
                     return mem;


                }
```

i see output as

```
            PS C:\VSB-PRO> node Fibo.js
            [ 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN ]
```

Here is the reference code trying to convert which was previously written  in Java

```
            class Solution {
            public:
                vector<int> countBits(int num) {
                    //mem[i] = No of 1s from 0 to number i
                    vector<int> mem(num+1);
                    mem[0] = 0;
                    
                    for(int i=1;i<=num;++i)
                        mem[i] = mem[i/2] + i%2;
                    
                    return mem;
                }
            };
```

Your help is very much appreciated

Regards,

Carolyn

Comment: `for (int i=1;i<=nums;i++)` will produce a SyntaxError, and `mem[i/2]` will not exist for odd numbers, hence NaN

Comment: strange looking JavaScript

Comment: What do you think `mem[i/2]` would be ?`mem[.5]` for 1......

Comment: updated the for loop to remove syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that in Java `/` represents integer division when the operands are integers, but in JavaScript, the division will be a floating point division, so that 1/2 == 0.5, and then `mem[0.5]` will be an undefined value.

Use the bit shift operator instead to get the same behaviour:

```js
const countBits = function(nums) {
  let mem = [0];
  for (let i = 0; i <= nums; i++)
    mem[i] = mem[i >> 1] + i % 2;
  return mem;
}

console.log(countBits(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting positive numbers to a Javascript string object will work for you

```js
console.log(Number(256).toString(2)); // 100000000
```

If your array contains both positive and negative numbers, then you can use the "[unsigned right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift)" operator with toString method again.

```js
console.log((-256 >>> 0).toString(2)); // 11111111111111111111111100000000
```